# Return one true/false when checking multiple items in XQuery

Tags: xml, xquery, soapui

```
<Response>
    <List>
        <item>
            <Date>2019-01-01</Date>
        </item>
        <item>
            <Date>2020-01-11</Date>
        </item>
        <item>
            <Date>2021-03-01</Date>
        </item>
    </List>
</Response>
```

I try to get one false / true in an expression in XQuery, but it only works for every  value.

```
let $Dates := //Response/List/item[*]/Date
for $Date in $Dates
return if ( $Date>='2020-01-01' and $Date<='2021-01-01') 
then true
else false
```

Result:

```
false
true
false
```

There was also an attempt to do so:

```
let $Date := //Response/List/item[*]/Date
return 
fn:boolean($Date>='2019-01-01' and $Date<='2019-12-31')
```

In this case, returns false only if all elements do not satisfy the check.

p.s: This is planned to be used in Assertions in SoapUI, so if you have other solutions, please write too.

p.s2: I apologize for my English, I use a translator.

Comment: Which is the exact and complete result you want? Which condition do you want to check?

Comment: @MartinHonnen If at least one of the Date value (2019-01-01, 2020-01-11, 2021-03-01) is out of the range (2020-01-01 - 2021-01-01), the result is false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use Quantified Expressions.

Check it out here: [XQuery/Quantified Expressions](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/XQuery/Quantified_Expressions)

Along the following.

> XPath

```
every $Date in /Response/List/item/Date/text()
satisfies ($Date>='2020-01-01' and $Date<='2021-01-01')
```

Comment: I think the `every .. satisfies` suggestion is fine but I wonder why you select down to the `text()` child node instead of simply selecting the element with `every $Date in /Response/List/item/Date`.

Comment: Just to make sure that we are checking textual value and not the Date element. It all depends on how smart the XPath/XQuery, etc. engine of the OP. And I tested it on my machine. The suggested Quantified Expression is working correctly.

Comment: Yes, the quantified expression is fine. But I don't understand the `/text()` node selection nor your explanation for that. In what way would `every $Date in /Response/List/item/Date` go wrong if the XPath/XQuery engine were not smart enough?

Comment: Otherwise, it will be comparison of XML element data type vs. date data type. It is all about data types. So it is an explicit data type conversion instead of implied. Usually, data type casting is done in the `satisfies` clause.

Comment: Are you assuming a schema which defines the element `Date` to have an `xs:date` data type? Or where in the example is a `date` data type comparison done or would be done? Your code uses string comparison and not date comparison.